# Using the Modern Script Editor web part in SPO, the type value of script tag is being modified to "pnp" + extra attrib. of pnpname w/string as value

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts, script, script-editor-webpart

Using the Modern Script Editor web part in an instance of SharePoint Modern Online, when adding third-party embed codes that contain script tags, the type value of script tag is being modified to "pnp" and an additional data attribute of pnpname is being added with a string of letters, numbers and hyphens as the value.

For example, if this script tag is added within the web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain-of-file/jsfile.js" data-attrubite="value"></script>
```

It is being changed to this:

```
<script type="pnp" src="https://domain-of-file/jsfile.js" data-attribute="value" pnpname="e979e7cc-671e-4406-b64b-a815dcc44037"></script>
```

This change is resulting in the following error in the browser console:

**Failed to load resource: domain-of-file/jsfil...pnp=1699299773589:1 net::ERR_FAILED**

This is of course preventing necessary JavaScript from running and causing issues with the third-party element we're trying to embed.

This is the web part we're using:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor

It was downloaded already compiled from here:
https://sharepointshepherd.com/product/pzl-script-editor/

We have been through all the settings in SharePoint we can think of, and have not been able to figure this out.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!